# Rails 4 - Where() search to display data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three tables: `illness`, `symptom` and a secondary table to link the other two on a `has_many through:` relationship.

I wish to implement a system where users type in their symptoms and receive a list of possible illnesses. 
With what I already have implemented I can search for symptoms and get a list of those, but I want to display a list of illnesses that fit the informed symptom(s).

For example: 
User types in "Fever" and "Sneezing". System finds the `symptoms` with those names (let's say they have IDs of 1 and 2 respectively) and displays "Common Cold", an entry on the `illnesses` table that has symptoms 1 and 2 associated with it.

This is what I already have implemented:

Symptom.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where( 'name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").all
    else
        all
    end
end
```

Symptoms_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @symptoms = Symptom.search(params[:search])
  @symptoms = @Symptoms.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 5)
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
   <%= form_tag sintomas_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
     </p>
  <% end %>
```

I assume I have to change the code in both the index action and the `if search where()` code, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Illness < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :illness_symptoms, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :ilness
  has_many :symptoms, through: ilness_symptoms

  def self.for_symptoms(*s)
    Illness.scoped.join(:symptoms).merge(Symptom.symptoms(s))
  end
end

class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base
  def symptoms(*args)
    where("symptoms.symptom in (?)" , args.flatten.compact.uniq)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's giving me an error and asking for tASSOC (which apparently is =>) in the self.for_symptoms def

Comment: Had a typo.. try again.. :)

Comment: It seems to work now. Though I'm unsure about the logic behind it. I'd have to alter a few things more for this to work, correct? Like adding more fields to the form and editing the search method?